# $a\in \mathbb F_{q}^{*}$ is the $k-th$ power of element of $\mathbb F_{q}$ if and only if, $a^{\frac {q-1}{d}}=1$, where $d=gcd(q-1,k)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

prove that for given $k\in \mathbb{N}$ the element $a\in \mathbb F_{q}^{*}$ is the $k-th$ power of element of $\mathbb F_{q}$ if and only if, $a^{\frac {q-1}{d}}=1$, where $d=gcd(q-1,k)$.

**my approach**
let $b\in \mathbb F_{q}$ such that $a=b^{k}$ and $b \neq 0$, then

$$a^{\frac {q-1}{d}}=(b^{k})^{\frac {q-1}{d}}=(b^{q-1})^{\frac {k}{d}}=1^{k/d}=1.$$
I'm having trouble demonstrating the other implication
in the other case, if  $a^{\frac {q-1}{d}}=1$, Should I use the fact that $F_ {q}^{*}$ is cyclic?

Comment: Using a generator of $\mathbb{F}_q^*$ gives a quick proof. You can also show that the polynomial $X^{(q-1)/d}-1 \in \mathbb{F}_q[X]$ has a multiple who is split with simple roots, so has exactly $(q-1)/d$ roots in $\mathbb{F}_q$. It has all of the $b^d$, $b \in \mathbb{F}_q^*$, as roots, so these are the only roots.

Comment: You should **show** that $F_q^*$ is cyclic

Comment: I show that $F_q^*$ Is cyclic, but how to show the above